# Contact Form - Append ".html" from URL after POST

Tags: javascript, html, forms

there may be a bit more to this, but I haven't been able to figure this out.

What I have is a contact form on multiple pages that all post to the same "thankyou.html" page. With the exception of the index file, every other page has a ".html" extension to the end of name which makes it so the form cannot redirect to correct page after the form POST.

Example: User Fills out form > Form POST > redirects to URL below

URL of current form POST: http://www.example.com/sub-domain.html/thankyou.html?(query parameters)

What I want he URL to redirect as: http://www.example.com/sub-domain/thankyou.html?(query parameters)

I already pull in the URL parameters I require using `getUrlVars`

So my main question is.

How can I append ".html" from the variable `subdomain` so the form can post properly to the thankyou.html page?

```
    // Pulls in URL parameters
    var subdomain = window.location.pathname;
    var variable = getUrlVars()["Var1"];
    var variable2 = getUrlVars()["Var2"];
    $('input[name="xxRedir"]').val('http://www.example.com' + subdomain + 
   '/thankyou?Var1=' + variable + "&Var2=" + variable2);
```

Comment: Not sure exactly what you mean. Do you mean append ".html" TO subdomain or remove it from the string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to strip a trailing `.html` from a string you can just use regex and replace it:

```
var subdomain = window.location.pathname.replace(/\.html$/, '');
```

Comment: Accepted. So essentially for the variable subdomain it will equal the URL, but will replace the URL minus the ".html" and return it a value of ''?